# The purpose that "in order to" introduces is related to the main subject?

Tags: usage

This question might sound stupid, but I found that the purpose that "in order to" introduces is related to the main subject.

I don't know if there is a term for this and I don't know if there are somewhere else this concept can also apply.

Is there a name or concept for this? Do you agree on what I found?

Examples:

> (1) I want to give my girlfriend a gift so that she can be happy.

can not be changed to:

> (2) I want to give my girlfriend a gift to be happy because (2) sounds like I want to be happy by giving my girlfriend a gift.

---

> (3) I throw the glass at the wall so that it breaks into pieces.

can not be changed to:

> (4) I throw the glass at the wall in order to break into pieces.
> because (4) sounds like "I" break into pieces.

---

> (5) I picked up trash along the beach in order to save the planet Earth.
> => Although what I did isn't really helpful in terms of saving the planet, the sentence just works. I think it is because "I picked up trash along the beach" and "I save the planet Earth" have the same subject "I".

Comment: (2) could be _to make her happy_, and (4) _to break it into pieces_.

Comment: (3) *I throw the glass at the wall so that it breaks into pieces* becomes (4) *I throw the glass at the wall in order to break **it** into pieces*. Your examples are all a bit "strange" to me, but consider ***I gave her an engagement ring to impress her mother***. The words themselves tell us *nothing* about whether the purpose was that her mother should be impressed with ***me***, or with her daughter (my intended future wife).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

(It makes no difference whether we use ***to, in order to, so that,...*** in such contexts)

> 1: *I paid her parking fines to avoid going to jail*
> (implies that if I *hadn't* paid her fines, ***I*** would go to jail)

> 2: *I paid her parking fines to avoid **her** going to jail*
> (implies that if I hadn't paid her fines, ***she*** would go to jail)

Note that in my example #1, there's an "unstated subject" (***who*** avoids going to jail?). In such contexts, if the subject is omitted from the ***auxiliary*** clause, it's always the same as the one in the associated ***main*** clause. Note that all that's happening here is we're "deleting" a "predictably repeated element" in the auxiliary clause. My first example could just as well have been...

> 1a: *I paid her parking fines to avoid **me** going to jail*